# How to secure an open port for SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, security, port-forwarding, file-transfer

I'm trying to set up a media sever for my parents at home so they can rip the disks (that they own of course), and stream it from anywhere in the house. My issue arises when I want to be able to transfer files into the computer that is housing the videos and such, when I'm away.

I want to be able to SSH into the computer and put files in and move them to where they need to go.

I understand that I need to port forward in order to be able to access it, but then I have an open port and it is my understanding that it is more or less like an open door in the network, is this the case and do I need to worry about such a thing or is it more like assign the port and tell no one.

I did see something on another post mentioning port knocking here
[I own an FTP server, and need port 21 open, how do I keep it secure?](https://superuser.com/questions/288633/i-own-an-ftp-server-and-need-port-21-open-how-do-i-keep-it-secure)

Would that be a good solution, or other methods I should pressure?

info:
network consists of a modem+wireless+router->computer with Plex
and all other devices are connected via wireless connectivity and since the port would be open I'm concerned about the other devices being vulnerable to attacks if the ports open

Comment: Does your router support a VPN server?  Many do and then you won't need to open any ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is my understanding that it is more or less like an open door in the network

No, that's not how ports work.

Being able to connect to a specific port (TCP or UDP) only lets you talk *to the specific service* that is listening for connections on that port. So if TCP port 22 on your computer is "open" by OpenSSH, it just goes to the OpenSSH server and nowhere else.

The "open door" part has more to do with the *actual service* not being properly secured. For example, if you decided to open the RDP (Windows Remote Desktop) service to the internet, there would be a very high risk because of the service, as there have been many exploits that affect Windows' RDP service, e.g. authentication bypasses. But, in the end, the attacker would still have to go through the RDP service in *some* way or other.

OpenSSH is usually considered to be low-risk, with most issues coming from account configuration (weak passwords) and not from the server software itself. It does not have a history of allowing attackers to do much anything if they don't log in first. If you apply the usual mitigations such as requiring non-password-based logon, you should be good.

(Note that not all SSH implementations are equally good, e.g. it is still risky to allow direct ssh into routers, toasters, or other embedded devices.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was planning on useing ssh keygen as far as that is concerned, but I have to ask, why are people so concerned with leaving a port open? Is that because inside of the router you have specify that the port can only be used for that service on a specific machine? Thanks for the insight

Comment: I'd disagree about ssh being low-risk. You're right that the main problem is weak passwords, but those're fairly common, and password-guessing attacks on ssh are *very* common. If you're going to expose ssh to the internet, set up public-key authentication, and configure the ssh service to [reject anything else](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346857/how-do-i-force-ssh-to-only-allow-users-with-a-key-to-log-in).

Answer (score 1):

> i understand that I need to port forward in order to be able to access it, but then I have an open port and it is my understanding that it is more or less like an open door in the network, is this the case and do I need to worry about such a thing or is it more like assign the port and tell no one

Ports are assigned to individual processes--a process will listen on an IP and port, and any traffic received on  that IP+port (that combination is called a *socket*) will go to that process.

So a port is an "open door" to a process.

It's not an open door into the network unless the process allows that access or gets tricked into allowing that access.

In your case, the process is (probably OpenSSH's) `sshd` - which does allow remote login, remote file access, and can potentially grant an attacker a lot of power over your system.

Ways to prevent your processes from doing more than they should if an attacker does something bad:

- Is the process running with the least privilege possible? (*sshd* has to run as root because it allows login - so unfortunately you can't do much there)
- Are you running the latest version/applying all security patches (make sure OpenSSH is updated and enable automatic updates)
- Is the process configured securely? (for example, you should disallow root login from `sshd.conf` and consider using keys instead of passwords)
- Are you monitoring the process to check for unusual activity (keep an eye on `/var/log/auth.log` and consider learning about and setting up `fail2ban`).
- Are your passwords to login to the system secure and regularly changed?

Furthermore for `sshd` the following is a good idea:

- Both SSH, as well as the common implementation OpenSSH, have been around a while and are extensively used.  OpenSSH is developed by the OpenBSD project which has an excellent reputation for security.  You can totally make it insecure if you don't configure it right, so study the configuration options.
- Disable X forwarding and other features if not needed.  You'll need to study all the options in the `sshd.conf` file.
- Disable root login via password - it's best to disable root login entirely.
- If you leave it running on the default port 22, you'll get a lot of automated password guesses by random IPs. Use a different port.  If someone says this is "security by obscurity" - that's normally good advice but you're still better off using a different port.
- Use keys instead of passwords.  Most if not all SFTP/SCP clients will support keys.

Comment: im aware of the implacations of allowing ssh outside of the homenetwork and I'm going requiring keys for devices with a passcode (not something someone could brute force) and try to see if I can set up fail to ban as well.